# Can't connect internet 16.04 and ping doesn't work

Tags: networking, internet, dhcp, router, ping

I installed 16.04 and nothing setup to internet connection.

DHCP fails to get dynamic IP

so I changed to static, detail is:
ip      : 10.0.2.200
gateway : 10.0.0.1
netmask : 255.255.0.0

But in both of two cases, ping doesn't work to gateway or other computers which in same gateway. Only shows "destination host unreachable", even if target computer is in same hub..

(Computer's IP running correctly is 10.0.2.100 and other options are identical)

ifconfig shows me that Rx bytes is increasing whenever I typed it in case both of DHCP and static.

I don't know why Rx bytes is increasing, and where packets come from.

How can I fix it? I think this is nonsense.

Comment: Please add the exact contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` to your question.

Comment: Solved with dumbfounded. The reason is UTP CABLE. thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, start troubleshooting by pinging your loopback address to make sure that your TCP/IP protocol stack is working properly:

```
$ ping -c 4 -i 1 127.0.0.1
```

Temporarily, configure your network interface (this will not survive a reboot, that's why I say temporarily):

```
$ sudo ifconfig [INTERFACE] 10.0.2.200 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 10.0.255.255
```

Ping your new IP address to see that it's working:

```
$ ping -c 4 -i 1 10.0.2.200
```

On another computer, do the same thing (assign it an address of 10.0.2.201) and try pining the 10.0.2.200 host from it. Then report what kind of results you observe. I'll amend my post as you progress in your troubleshooting activities. At this point there is not much that can be said given the scarce information we've been provided.